# How to get context information in Javascript from the Sharepoint ECB menu items - CAMOpt

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-2010, ecb

I want to hide specific menu items in the ECB of a sharepoint list, in function of the item the ECB is opend for.

I overloaded the CAMOpt function to hide some context menus for all listitems.  That works , but now I want to hide some context menus in function of the status of the selected item.

Therefore I would need to get more info about the item the Context Menu relates to.

Is there a way to get context information?